# Downloading file from URL using start chrome

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that opens a URL to download a csv file, then I need to move and then rename that csv form downloads folder to other one.

What I have is:

```
@echo off

SET CCDIR=C:\Users\(username)\Desktop
SET LOADDIR=C:\Users\(username)\Downloads

ECHO ***************************************************************************
ECHO  Downloading the file
ECHO ***************************************************************************

start chrome (URL string)

:NEXT

ECHO ***************************************************************************
ECHO  Move CSV file from Downloads folder to Desktop
ECHO ***************************************************************************

move %LOADDIR%\*(file string)* %CCDIR%
ren %CCDIR%\*(file string)* (new file name)
```

I want to execute it all in the same bat, but just the start chrome is working, the bat is ignoring the move and ren.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use curl, wget or powershell Invoke-Webrequest to do the download. Your (pretty scrambledd) batch won't wait for the download to finish before trying to move and rename it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer LotPings, so what do you mean is use wget command in the batch instead of "start chrome"? That will make the same effect?

Comment: Yes, `wget` is a program meant for downloading files from the internet without needing to open a web browser. This will make your script significantly faster and more portable.

Comment: [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) are 3rd party apps  where the latter is also part of the [very lastest Windows 10 version](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/12/19/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/). Powershell is contained since Windows 7 and has the similar cmdlet [Invoke-Webrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-3.0)

Comment: LotPings, thanks that is a good advise, I knew about wget, eventhough i don't have admin privileges to install wget in the laptop where I'm scheduling the tasks. Thnaks a lot, regards.,

Comment: You can download files with `certutil` command.
 [Take a look at this example](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8485)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my comment, you can give a try for this example to download a file with `Certuil command`

```dos
@echo off
Title Downloading a file using Certutil Command
Mode 70,5 & color 0A
SET CCDIR=%userprofile%\Desktop
SET LOADDIR=%userprofile%\Downloads
set "url=https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip"
echo(
ECHO   ******************************************************************
ECHO          Please wait a while ... Downloading the file ...
ECHO   ******************************************************************
Call :download %url% %LOADDIR%
Rem Moving the downloaded file from the folder Downloads to Desktop
move /Y "%file%" "%CCDIR%\">nul
Rem Open the desktop folder with explorer
Explorer "%CCDIR%\"
goto :eof
::--------------------------------------------
:Download <Url> <File>
Set url="%~1"
Set file=%2\%~nx1
certutil.exe -urlcache -split -f %url% %file%>nul
Rem Deleting cache
certutil -urlcache "%~1" delete>nul
Rem Check referenced urlcache is deleted
certutil.exe -v -urlcache -split "%~1">nul
exit /b
::--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Hackoo, thanks for your advise, I will try this shortly, Regards.